# Typescript Array of Typed Classes

Tags: arrays, typescript, class, strong-typing

I am new to to development overall, so please pardon my ignorance.I am trying to understand how to use Typescript classes to combine two arrays of a given class

Using the following example the ValidationError class consists of a property and an error message. The MyErrors class is an array of the ValidationError class. I have various modules that will return a MyErrors and want to then concatenate them into a single array of ValidationErrors

Ultimately I would like it to look something like the following:

```js
let allErrors = new MyErrors

allErrors.add("property_a","there was an error with property a") // add an error in the main module

let module_a = returns a MyErrors array
let module_b = returns a MyErrors array

allErrors.addAll(module_a) // Add all errors returned from module_a to allErrors 
allErrors.addAll(module_b) // Add all errors returned from module_b to allErrors 
//allErrors should now be an array of ValidationError items the include the items from the main module, module_a and module_b
```

Below is my starting place:

```js
export class ValidationError  {
    public property: string
    public error: string
    constructor(property: string, error: string){
        this.property = property;
        this.error = error;
    };  
}

export class MyErrors extends Array<ValidationError>{
    add(property: string,error: string) {
        let newError = new ValidationError(property,error);
        return this.push(newError);
    }
    addAll(errors: MyErrors) {
        return this.concat(errors); //MyErrors instance that concatenates to the declared instance
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you want without extending `Array` at all.
The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows you to call `Array.push()` with elements from another array.

```js
const allErrors: ValidationError[] = [];

allErrors.push(new ValidationError("property", "error"));

const moduleA: ValidationError[] = [ /* ... */ ];
const moduleB: ValidationError[] = [ /* ... */ ];

// Here's the nice bit using the spread syntax
allErrors.push(...moduleA, ...moduleB);
```